# sparse solution in dense linear system of equations in scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-analysis

I have a dense over-determined matrix. I can find solutions with `np.linalg.lstsq`. I want to get an answer with mostly 0s.

Here is an artificial example that produces similar results to my code:

```
import numpy as np
# Build matrix and vector
M = np.array([[2.71*i, 3.14*i, 4*i, 5.99*i, 6*i] for i in range(1, 1000) ])
v = np.array([[i] for i in range(1, 1000)])
solution, _, _, _ = np.linalg.lstsq(M, v)
print("solution", solution)
# print("error", np.linalg.norm(v - np.dot(M, solution)))
```

I got solution with many small non-zero terms.

```
solution [[ 0.06342455]
 [ 0.1076765 ]
 [ 0.12445127]
 [-0.00251504]
 [ 0.00121254]]
```

The solution is not unique and I would like to also have `solution` to be mostly 0s. Like `[0, 0, -.5, 0, .5]` or `[1/2.71, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Do you have 5 variables and 1000 equations?

Comment: No more than 5, many more than 1000.

Comment: But in this example, you have an overdetermined system, when you have a solution the other solutions are linear combination.

Comment: Yes, it is over-determined. So there is infinite number of solutions. I want to select from those solutions those which are mostly zeros.

Comment: I would exploit the very small amount of variables and solve all variants where *some* vars are a-priori fixed to 0 (variant A: preprocesss/modify to use the same solver on other data; variant B: use a bound-constrained solver to fix them and reuse the data).